# How to apply ActiveSupport::Concern to specific actions in my controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, activesupport-concern

I'm using Grape to build an API.

I created an `ActiveSupport::Concern` let's say with the name `Authentication` and I applied some before filter so my concern looks like:

```
module Authentication
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before do
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless authenticated?
    end
    ....
  end
end
```

Now let's say in my UserController I want to apply this concern only for a specific action. How can I do that?

```
  class SocialMessagesController < Grape::API
    include Authentication

    get '/action_one' do
    end

    get '/action_two' do
    end

  end
```

Any easy way to specify the concern for a specific method just like `before_filter` in rails with `only` option?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your actions into different classes and then mount them within a wrapper class:

```rb
class SocialMessagesOne < Grape::API
  include Authentication

  get '/action_one' do
    # Subject to the Authentication concern
  end
end
```

```rb
class SocialMessagesTwo < Grape::API
  get '/action_two' do
    # Not subject to the Authentication concern
  end
end
```

```rb
class SocialMessagesController < Grape::API
  mount SocialMessagesOne
  mount SocialMessagesTwo
end
```

More information on mounting is available in [the Grape README](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/#mounting).